# Minor cosmetic bug when two users make the same edit at the same time

Tags: bug, tags, edits

This must be very rare and unlikely, but...

I found out that if two users edit the same post and make the same edit, the same second, the edit log turns weird:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53432535/revisions

In edit 2 and 3 two users removed the C++ tag at the very same second. The 3rd edit appears in the log as if it changed nothing.

Not exactly a top priority bug to fix, but I'm reporting this in case there's some underlying issue beyond the cosmetic, maybe some manner of race condition when two users submit the edit at the same time.

Comment: Yeah... same thing happens if two mods happen to delete a post roughly at the same time... it shows as deleted by two diamonds... so it's not just edits that do this...

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/deadlocked/